# How can I detect circles in python with a set of (x, y) points

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, object-detection, points

I have a list of (x,y) points that constitue several circles with different centers, they all have the same diameter (which is known).
I need to detect the number of circles in total (not necessary to define their parameters). Is there a simple way to do that in python? (preferably without openCV)

Comment: maybe it need Machine Learnimg and something like [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)

Answer (score 0):

If all circles have the same size and they **do not intersect**, you can just scan the picture line-by-line, pixel-by-pixel.

When you meet a pixel of circle color, apply [flood-fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm from this point and mark all **connected** pixels of the same color with the same integer value (1 for the first circle and so on).

After all the last value is number of objects.

Aslo you can use [connected-component labelling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)